# Cant use NSMutableDictionary key as index in array?

Tags: ios, swift, key, nsmutabledictionary

I want to use an `NSMutableDictionary key` as an index in an array. The following is my attempt:

```
   for (key, value) in item.attendeesImages(){
        println("Key: \(key) value: \(value)")
        if cell.attendeesImage.count > key as! Int {
            cell.attendeesImage[key].image = value as? UIImage
            cell.attendeesImage[key].clipsToBounds = true
            cell.attendeesImage[key].layer.cornerRadius = cell.attendeesImage[key as! Int].frame.size.width/2
        }
    }
```

However, when I try to do this, I get an error saying:

```
Could not find member 'image', 'clipsToBounds', and 'cornerRadius'
```

I am confused because I stored the key as an `Int` originally so I tried to take out the typecasting in the if statement and I get an error saying"

```
Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'AnyObject'
```

I'm just a little confused and would appreciate some help with this. Thanks!

Comment: An array can only be indexed by an Int, not an arbitrary key.  What are the key values for `item.attendeesImages`?  You can't store Ints in an NSMutableDictionary, you must store objects, so perhaps you have stored `NSNumber` instances with the value set by an int?  But, why would you do this when you could just use an array?

Comment: @Paulw11 the keys are simply numbers like 0, 1, 2, etc. and the the values are UIImages. My goal was that as I loop through the `attendeesImages` `NSMutableDictionary`, I could use each key as an index in `cell.attendeesImages`

Comment: They can be numbers because you can't store types like int in an `NSMutableDictionary` - they must be either `NSNumber`s or `String`s "1","2","3'.  If it is a swift dictionary then you can store Ints but you have to downcast the key to an Int - which is why  you are getting an error about AnyObject.  If you remove the `if` statement and it's associated code what values are logged on the console by your print statement?

Comment: @Paulw11 If I remove the `if` statement, I need to cast the keys into `Ints` when setting the `image`, `clipToBounds`, and `cornerRadius`. However, in doing so, my program breaks because I get an error saying `fatal error: Array index out of range`. I found that I am trying to access an index, that can possibly exceed the `cell.attendeesImage` range as per this question here which is why I added in that `if statement`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27641761/swift-fatal-error-array-index-out-of-range. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I suggested removing the if statement simply to try and understand what the type of key is.  If the dictionary and array are related together properly then you should never get an array index that is out of range.  As I said in my earlier comment, I don't understand why you would use a dictionary with ints as keys - that is more simply achieved as an array. How are you building this dictionary?

Comment: @Paulw11 that actually solved the problem. If you make an answer I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Array's don't have keys like dictionaries do. For example:

```
    var anArray = ["A","B","C"]
    // anArray[0] == "A"
    // anArray[1] == "B"
    // anArray[2] == "C"
    var aDict = ["itemOne": "A", "itemTwo": "B","itemThree": "C"
    //  aDict["itemOne"] == "A"
```

When you use the for in loop, your for value in (array/dictionary) is passed as `AnyObject` because swift doesn't know what the values in the array or the dictionary are going to be.

Also unless you are dealing with some NS libraries that don't accept the new swiftier Dictionary data type, you should be using Dictionary instead of the old NSDictionary.

Apple has some great documentation on iterating over Dictionaries using For in Loops, and some neat tricks using the .keys and .values modifiers.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html