# Swift: How to prevent two table cells to be swiped at the same time?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a table view with cells that the user can swipe to delete the row. I'm receiving a `fatal error: Index out of range` error whenever I swipe two rows at once (with two fingers, one on each row).

I've added these 4 lines in my `OrdersViewController`:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    self.view.isMultipleTouchEnabled = false
    self.view.isExclusiveTouch = true
    self.ordersTable.isMultipleTouchEnabled = false
    self.ordersTable.isExclusiveTouch = true
  }
```

in an effort to try to change this behavior so that only one cell is swiped at a time, but nothing has changed. I can still use two fingers on two different rows to swipe back and forth at the same time.

Is there another way?

None of the IsExclusiveTouch and IsMultipleTouchEnabled is working regardless of where I put it. I wonder if it has anything to do with me using this library github.com/alikaragoz/MCSwipeTableViewCell

It could also be because I'm using Firebase?

Comment: "Index out of range" in a table view usually means that there is some inconsistency in your data source methods.

Comment: Is your question *"How to prevent two table cells to be swiped at the same time?"* or is is that an XY-problem and your real question is *"How to fix this out of range error?"* – If it is the latter then you should show your data source methods, and more information about the fatal error (where does it occur, what is the stack backtrace, ...)

Comment: I'd rather fix the former. None of the IsExclusiveTouch and IsMultipleTouchEnabled is working regardless of where I put it. I wonder if it has anything to do with me using this library https://github.com/alikaragoz/MCSwipeTableViewCell

Comment: I had similar problems. Tried loads of things but ended up with an ugly solution of having a property `isPanning` in the view controller to prevent this from happening.

Comment: @Eendje i was thinking of the same thing. what methods did you toggle that var in? i'm looking for a method that tells me when a cell is the middle of being swiped

Comment: check this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27641761/swift-fatal-error-array-index-out-of-range

Comment: @Edmund: in `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin`.

Comment: @Eendje perfect! it run every time you are about to swipe one of the rows. i think this could block the UI so nothing can do a multi update, which is fine with me!

Comment: @Eendje hm do you know the callback for when the gesture ends? like a `gestureRecognizerShouldEnd`. i need to turn the flag off when the user lets go

Comment: @Edmund: Yea I've set `isUserInteractionEnabled` to `false` to prevent the other cells from being panned. As for turning the flag off, I've done that in the recognizer's `.ended || .canceled` state.

Answer (score 0):

First of all set delegates of gesture and then use this delegate, it could help you :

```
override func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually did this, using the callbacks made available by the table cell pod i'm using:

```
class OrderTableManager {
  static var swiping = false
}

class OrderPreparingTableViewCell: MCSwipeTableViewCell, MCSwipeTableViewCellDelegate {
  override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if !OrderTableManager.swiping {
      OrderTableManager.swiping = true
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }

  // MARK: Public
  func swipeTableViewCellDidEndSwiping(_ cell: MCSwipeTableViewCell!) {
    OrderTableManager.swiping = false
  }

  func displayOrder(order: AppState.Order, clock: Clock, fDone: @escaping SwipeHandler, fDelete: @escaping SwipeHandler) -> OrderPreparingTableViewCell {
    ...

    self.delegate = self

    ...
  }
```